# Объекты при работе с VBA и Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell

Всем привет.

В программировании не силен, но представляю классы и объекты на более-менее поверхностном уровне.
Класс (в котором описаны свойства и методы) - Объекты (к которым мы можем применить методы и свойства класса).
Исходя из этих "познаний" возникло два вопроса при работе с VBA и Powershell. Далее примеры:

------Объект .NET------

```
$newObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.EventLog -ArgumentList Application
```

Общий смысл понимаю как, "Создаем новый объект класса System.Diagnostics.EventLog и помещаем ссылку на этот объект в переменную $newObj". Далее мы можем вызывать методы и просматривать свойства данного объекта.

------Объект COM------

```
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\PS\ad_users.xlsx")
```

Создается COM объект, а потом, мы обращаемся к свойству Workbooks (которое на самом деле самостоятельный объект, у которого и есть свойство Open, у которого мы запрашиваем метод Open...

Или это все совсем по другому?

Если у объектов через точку вызываются методы и свойства, то как понять эту конструкцию?
В моем понимании через созданный мной объект, вызываем другой объект, через точку, у которого мы вызываем метод.

Как называется данный подход/практика/метод, не знаю как это назвать?
Либо же, объясните, пожалуйста, если я все понимаю неправильно.

Пока писал вопрос, наткнулся на одну вещь, которая возможно все объясняет, но я не могу понять ее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написано: Use the Worksheets property of the Workbook object to return the Worksheets collection.

И тут же слева на панели, видно ОБЪЕКТ Worksheets, а не свойство Worksheets объекта Workbook, хотя оно есть и там.

Я окончательно запутался.

Answer (score 0):

Александр, вы всё правильно и замечательно понимаете.

"И тут же слева на панели, видно ОБЪЕКТ Worksheets, а не свойство Worksheets объекта Workbook, хотя оно есть и там." Свойство Worksheets объекта Workbook содержит ссылку на объект Worksheets, который и отображается как значение свойства Worksheets.